# Is nginx upstream_response_time only meaningful when there are upstream servers?

Tags: nginx

Is nginx upstream_response_time only meaningful when there are upstream servers? If nginx directly returns the response to the client and nginx does not act as a reverse proxy, is it upstream_ Response_ Time has no value?

I observed there are a considerable number of upstream_response_time' value is hyphen in the access_log